# Alfresco Javascript Api SetPermission how to create URL?

Tags: javascript, api, url, alfresco

I want Adding Permissions using Alfresco Javascript API, i do like  [here](https://anythingalfresco.wordpress.com/tag/search-lucenesearch/)

Know I want to change the Url like this :

```
<url>/set/folder/permission/?folderName={folderName}&permi;={permi?}&username;={username?}</url>
```

but i have an error :

```
00130088 Failed to parse web script description document org/alfresco/sample/setPermission.get.desc.xml ; Error on line 4 of document : The entity "permi" was referenced, but not declared. Nested exception: The entity "permi" was referenced, but not declared. (workspace://SpacesStore/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:webscripts/org/alfresco/sample/setPermission.get.desc.xml)
```

Comment: That URL XML looks very odd, are you sure you don't want something like `&amp;permi={permi?}` instead?

Comment: I don't have idea, because i must create the url for permission javascript API of alfresco, i don't know if it is a correct way to create URL (look link top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting your XML wrong. Assuming you want a URL with optional parameters:

- folderName
- permi
- username

Then your `url` should be something like:

```
<url>/set/folder/permission/?folderName={folderName}&amp;permi={permi?}&amp;username={username?}</url>
```

The `&amp;` is the XML escaped form of the `&` in the URL, and not some magic Alfresco thing!